# kstrtoint in sysfs for c kernel module

Tags: c, kernel-module

Hi I am trying to use a kobject to write to a int array from sysfs. So the input is a char* and a size variable. I cant seem to get this to work however. My expected input is `"num1 num2 num3 "`

```
static ssize_t pids_store(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count) {

int num_count = 0;
int i = 0;
int result = 0;
int cur_pid = 0;
char *dst;
char *ddst;

printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_DEGUG: enter");

dst = buf;
ddst = buf;

printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_DEGUG:  size of buffer %d ",count);


while(ddst < (buf + sizeof(size_t)*count)) {
ddst ++;
if (ddst[0] == ' ') {
   result = kstrtoint(dst,10,&cur_pid);
   dst=ddst+1;

   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_DEGUG: kstrtoint suceeded %d ",cur_pid);
   printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_DEGUG: kstrtoint suceeded res: %d ",result);
   pids[num_count] = cur_pid;
   num_count += 1;
   }
}

for(i=0;i<num_count;i++) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_TEST: pid: %d \n", pids[i]);
}
printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_DEBUG: leaving\n");
return count;                                         
}
```

When I `echo "100 " > /sys/vt/vt7/pids` I get

```
[ 2765.712770] GPIO_DEGUG: enter 
[ 2765.724468] GPIO_DEGUG:  size of buffer 5 
[ 2765.735101] GPIO_DEGUG: kstrtoint suceeded 0 
[ 2765.746526] GPIO_DEGUG: kstrtoint suceeded res: -22 
[ 2765.757746] GPIO_DEBUG: leaving
```

I suppose this is an argument error any help would be nice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `kstrtoint` expects full string to contain **single integer value**. The only exception is a newline character at the end of the string:

> The string must be null-terminated, and may also include a single newline before its terminating null.

As you can see, string "100 " doesn't fit for that requirement: it contains exceeded space.

For parse only part of the string as an integer, you may use `simple_strtol`:

```
long val = simple_strtol(dst, &ddst, 10);
if(ddst == ddst) {/* Parsing has been failed. */};
```

While this function is marked as an obsolete, there is still some code in the kernel which uses it.

Another possibility is to use `sscanf`. It expects fixed number of integers in the string, but it is an usual situation with attributes: **having complex representation of the attributes is not recommended**:

> The conventions for sysfs state that each attribute should contain a single, human-readable value; if you have a lot of information to return, you may want to consider splitting it into multiple attributes.

([Linux Device Drivers 3, chapter 14](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch14.pdf)).

Comment: Originally I wanted to pass in a string of ints (process IDs )into the kernel module but I agree that it looks much better with just a variable for each single ID. Thanks for your help! cheers

Comment: The check in the example is partial, the caller has to check for overflow as well, which is kinda impossible with `simple_strtox()` family of functions.

Comment: May be absence of overflow checking is the reason of deprecation `simple_*` family of functions. But in the given case checking for overflow isn't strictly required. Possible design is expecting correct string input from the user. If expectation fails, then integer value will have different string representation than input, noting worse.

Answer (score -1):

The kstrtoint function is defined here:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/kstrtox.c#L245

If you notice the last value of *res defined in the function is the value you wish to use. In your case `cur_pid` should be the value in which you want to print, the result should always be zero if it was successful. I would suggest checking result to make sure that the conversion has succeeded.

This should work:

```
int cur_pid, result;
char *dst = NULL;

cur_pid = result = 0;
dst = buf;

result = kstrtoint(dst, 10, &cur_pid);
if (result)
     printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO_DEGUG: kstrtoint suceeded res: %d ", cur_pid);
else
     printk(KERN_INFO "ERROR");
```